# AngularJS conditional required

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, required

I want to validate a form if an input text has value, or another one, or both of them.

For example

```
<!-- if username has data -->
<div class="username">
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required
               minlength="4" maxlength="8"
               placeholder="4 to 8 characters long" />
    </div>

<!-- if nickname has data -->
<div class="nickname">
        <label for="nickname">Nickname:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname" required
               minlength="4" maxlength="8"
               placeholder="4 to 8 characters long" />
    </div>

<!-- or if both has data submit is enabled -->
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

**-- EDIT --**

Ok now I have something weird, it seems that the "&&" operator doesn't work in HTML, so I'm a bit stuck..

Actually, with your help, my button can be clicked if the condition is verified. But strangely : 
- Button is not disabled
- If the condition is not verified, my button doesn't display my ng-if message.

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="myForm" novalidate>
    <div class="card-body card-padding">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Firstname</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <tags-input ng-model="myForm.firstname"
                                    min-length="0"
                                    name="firstname"
                                    use-strings="true" class="form-control" required>
                        </tags-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <tags-input ng-model="myForm.name"
                                    min-length="0"
                                    name="name"
                                    use-strings="true" class="form-control" required>
                        </tags-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <tags-input ng-model="myForm.email"
                                    min-length="0"
                                    name="email"
                                    use-strings="true" class="form-control" required>
                        </tags-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <tags-input ng-model="myForm.username"
                                    min-length="0"
                                    name="username"
                                    use-strings="true" class="form-control" required>
                        </tags-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Nickname</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <tags-input ng-model="myForm.nickname"
                                    min-length="0"
                                    name="nickname"
                                    use-strings="true" class="form-control" required>
                        </tags-input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" data-ng-show="btnOk">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="button" data-ng-click="action()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                        ng-disabled="(!myForm.username.$valid || !myForm.nickname.$valid) && !myForm.email.$valid && !myForm.name.$valid && !myForm.firstname.$valid">
                    <span ng-if="(!myForm.username.$valid || !myForm.nickname.$valid) && !myForm.email.$valid && !myForm.name.$valid && !myForm.firstname.$valid">Some required fields are missing</span>
                    <span ng-if="(myForm.username.$valid || myForm.nickname.$valid) && myForm.email.$valid && myForm.name.$valid && myForm.firstname.$valid">{{button}}</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

How can I bypass this behavior ?

Comment: Please use this if useful for this or will try to solve for you.. http://next.plnkr.co/edit/lCRwhj?p=preview&preview

Comment: `ng-required` allows you to use a varaible to indicate 
if a field is required: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRequired

Comment: Wait, do you want to show `<div class="username">` if the `username` has data and show the `<div class="nickname">` if the `nickname` has data? or enabled the submit button if either of the previous mentioned has data? How is it? The question title is a little missleading according to the question body...

Comment: @Nathan Meyer, please, it would be really helpful if you could make a running snippet like the one a posted in my answer in order to reproduce your issue, posting also the current behavior and expected one ( since it's not very clear to me after your update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this by adding bool in my condition like:

```
<div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="button" data-ng-click="action()" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"
                                    ng-disabled="(myForm.firstname.$valid == false || myForm.name.$valid == false || myForm.email.$valid == false || (myForm.username.$valid == false && myForm.nickname.$valid == false))">
                                <span ng-if="(myForm.firstname.$valid == false || myForm.name.$valid == false || myForm.email.$valid == false || (myForm.username.$valid == false && myForm.nickname.$valid == false))">Some required fields are missing</span>
                                <span ng-if="(myForm.firstname.$valid && myForm.name.$valid && myForm.email.$valid && (myForm.username.$valid || myForm.nickname.$valid))">{{button}}</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

An option is to

- Enclose them inside a `form` (give it a name)
- Declare an `ng-model` for *username* and *nickname* inputs
- Put the conditionals using the `$valid`/`$invalid` options of the objects created by AngularJS for the form components:

See below working example:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function() {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="mForm" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as vm" novalidate>

  <!-- if username has data -->
  <div class="username">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.username" id="username" name="username" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" placeholder="4 to 8 characters long" />
  </div>

  <!-- if nickname has data -->
  <div class="nickname">
    <label for="nickname">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.nickname" id="nickname" name="nickname" required minlength="4" maxlength="8" placeholder="4 to 8 characters long" />
  </div>

  <!-- or if both has data submit is enabled -->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-disabled="mForm.username.$invalid && mForm.nickname.$invalid">

  <div>Valid: {{!!(mForm.username.$valid || mForm.nickname.$valid)}}</div>

  <form>
```

Comment: @NathanMeyer You're welcome! If this was useful to you, please [upvote](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) this question for future readers and consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if you think it answers your question.

Comment: Oh, ok,let me see

Comment: @NathanMeyer I see three new fields being used for these conditions here and now the submit button is not an `input`, but a `button`. Can you please update the html too?, although it good be a lot **better** if you could start a **new thread** for this new strange behavior and close this thread. In any case let me know in order to help you. If you close this thread remember to rollback your last edit, since it wouldn't fit with the initial question you made.